# fragment's onCreateView called multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have a Settings fragment whose `onCreateView` gets called multiple times. I have ViewPager which is inside of the fragment's layout and the fragment launches by a clicking on the settings icon from options menu in toolbar.

And I cannot just move the ViewPager to the activity because I want to be able to swipe back to the Previous Fragment.

Also,I tried removing the fragments in the backstack using

```java
for(int i=0;i< Objects.requireNonNull(fm).getBackStackEntryCount();++i){
      fm.popBackStackImmediate();
   }
```

but that did not help at all.

Fragment code:

```java
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    
    public SettingsFragment() {
   
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    @Deprecated
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        final CustomViewPager viewPager=rootview.findViewById(R.id.SettingsFragmentViewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new Adapter(getFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
                    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                    for(int i=0;i< Objects.requireNonNull(fm).getBackStackEntryCount();++i){
                        fm.popBackStackImmediate();
                    }
                    viewPager.removeOnPageChangeListener(this);
                }
            }


        });
        return rootview;
       
    }
```

Fragment's xml:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:background="#fff" android:animationCache="true"
                                                   android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentContainer"
                                                   android:clickable="true"
                                                   android:drawingCacheQuality="high" android:focusable="true">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/SettingsActivityToolbar" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Settings"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:id="@+id/Settings_textview"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings_icon_back"
                android:id="@+id/backPressButton"
                android:rotation="180" android:backgroundTint="#fff"
                android:background="@null"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/SettingsActivityToolbar"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:onClick="click" android:drawingCacheQuality="high"/>
        <TextView
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:id="@+id/linebreak1" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/backPressButton" android:background="#A1A8AC"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp" android:id="@+id/linebreak2"
                android:background="#A1A8AC"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch4"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="Test Test"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="47dp" android:id="@+id/switch4"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp" android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:thumbTint="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
                android:trackTint="@drawable/switch_track_selector" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/backPressButton" tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="67dp" android:id="@+id/update"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch4" android:onClick="onClickUpdate"
                android:focusable="true"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="test test"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_height="0dp" android:id="@+id/enter_version"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/update"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp" android:layout_marginEnd="206dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/update" android:focusable="true"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Check Update"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/update_textview"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText" android:layout_marginEnd="228dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/update" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/update"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:focusable="true"/>
        <com.testapp.test2.CustomViewPager
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.58000004"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentViewPager"
                />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The adapter I am using for ViewPager:

```java
public class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);

    }


    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            return new BlankFragment();
        }

        if(position==1){
            return new SettingsFragment();
        }


        return null;
        }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }


}
```

I see that in my adapter I am also returning `SettingsFragment`.Is there a way to return the fragment that was created when I clicked the settings button in the toolbar?

Btw, I add the fragment using this:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.updateId:
                Log.d("MAIN ACTIVITY---","ADDING FRAGMENT...");
                FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_right_in,0);
                ft.add(R.id.MainActivityConstraint,new SettingsFragment());
                ft.commit();
                Log.d("ACTIVITY---","Fragment added...");
                break;

               }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's because you are adding a new SettingsFragment. Instead of using ft.add, use ft.replace, and initialize a SettingsFragment when first starting your activity so you're not instantiating new ones.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, How do I add initialize the SettingsFragment when I start the activity? @GarrenFitzenreiter

Comment: Fragment mySettingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();

Comment: I tried your solution of replacing ```ft.add``` with ```ft.replace``` but ```onCreateView``` still gets executed like 3 times. Also,I added ```Fragment settingsFragment=new SettingsFragment``` in ```onCreate``` of my activity. Do I need to change something in the Adapter too or something? @GarrenFitzenreiter

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that you're trying to switch between a blank fragment and a settings fragment. You need a main activity to hold a viewpager component that holds those two fragments (Blank and Settings). Basically, you'll stay on the main activity but will be swiping between the Blank and Settings fragment that's inside the viewpager component.

Comment: You're trying to setup a viewpager inside of a fragment. You need to setup the viewpager in an activity. You then use the activity to define and set the adapter to the viewpager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use an external library called swipebacklayout instead of ViewPager.
You can check it out here. https://github.com/gongwen/swipebacklayout